# CSS Fix In Achievements For > 10 Reputation Loss Needed

Tags: bug, status-completed, achievements-dialog

I was checking my achievements this morning and saw the following:

> [image]

As you can see, the loss of 10 points due a user being removed isn't handled properly in the styling, causing the negative sign to not appear next to the number. A simple CSS fix would be to apply something like `white-space:nowrap` on the containing span, which would result in the much cleaner:

> [image]

Comment: FWIW, this is for any `-n` where `n > 0`, not *just* for "user was removed"; e.g. the "achievement" entry for losing rep due to adding a bounty will result in the same CSS bug.

Comment: When did they start using a full dash there?

Comment: @Matt - Updated the title

Comment: @j08691: Sorry... it's actually `n > 10` which triggers it, not `n > 0`... I did mean to write that in the first place, but what I was thinking apparently didn't correspond to what I typed :P.

Comment: Oh, I take that back. Apparently, the `n` was too small for my test. Managed to reproduce it for `n >= 10`

Comment: Why did you even bother trying to blur that text out?  It's still clearly legible.

Comment: @tmyklebu - Just to emphasize the line with the issue.

Comment: OK, that makes sense.  I thought you were trying to censor or hide something in the most ineffective possible way. :)

Comment: @j08691 That's what freehand red circles are for! ;)

Comment: @animuson I think they've always done it. Negative scores seem to be larger for more emphasis; SO wants you to know about negative trends more than positive trends?

Comment: Using a hyphen would be inappropriate. Hyphens are not minus signs. They are not used to indicate subtraction. An actual minus sign has the same width as a plus sign, lines up vertically with a plus sign, and has the Unicode code point 0x2212.

Comment: I can't repro this so far, tried up to `-100`. What browser are you using?

Comment: @Haney Chrome 37/Windows 7

Comment: Odd, I cannot reproduce it in Chrome either. Let me tinker a little more. Is everyone who is experiencing it using Chrome?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this up. I have pushed a code fix to create both the appropriate amount of spacing for the numbers in the achievements list, and to use a proper minus sign instead of dash. It will be live in the next production build (meta: > `rev 2014.9.11.2543`, q&a: > `rev 2014.9.11.1840`).